# Using socket.io in visual studio node.js project

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-2015, socket.io

I have a node js project in Visual Studio that uses express.  I want to add socket.io to my project like this:

```
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
```

However, the app.js file does not have a server variable.  It seems that app is returned in the app.js

```
module.exports = app;
```

Then app.listen, where a server would be created, is called outside of that file.  Does anyone know how to use socket.io in a visual studio node js project?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I put the socket io code in it's own module as follows:

```
//    ./myService.js
var socketIo = require('socket.io');

module.exports = {
    startService: function (server) {
        var io = socketIo(server);

        io.on('connection', function (socket) {
            socket.on('receive message', function (question) {
                io.emit('send message', question);
            });
        });
        return io;
    }
};
```

The visual studio project has a file "./bin/www" where the server variable is created. I then pass the server variable to the module like this:

```
var io = require('../myService');
io.startService(server);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can directly put the connection in "./bin/www" file like below

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
console.log('client connect');
socket.on('echo', function (data) {
    io.sockets.emit('message', data);
    });
});
```